# Root url "/" of the homepagecontroller gives http error 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have defined a controller using:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomePageController {
    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(@RequestParam(value = "logout", defaultValue = "false") final boolean logout, final Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectModel, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
 System.out.println("testing");return "homepage";
}
```

The control doesnt even come to the home method defined here and gives the response:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

However when I change the request mapping to `@RequestMapping("/test")`, I am able to get control in the home method defined above.

Why am I not able to hit the controller when the request mapping is defined with "/"? I need the root url to land me on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

Remove `@RequestMapping("/")` above HomePageController and add above specific method signature like below

```
public class HomePageController {
    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,path="/")
     public String home(@RequestParam(value = "logout", defaultValue = "false")....

}
```

Should work !

Comment: Tried this already, did not work

Comment: Check if your controller is available on classpath ! @ComponentScan should help , sometimes, if controller is available in a package different to source folder, this happens